# Angular 9 + jest : unit test, mock a promise and check method called then

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I need help, I don't know how to mock a promise and check a method is called after in the then() part.

My code looks like this, when I click on the save button of my form :

```
// File : myComponent.ts
save() {
   const myObject = new MyObject({field: this.form.value.field});

   this.myService.saveObject(myObject).then(() => { // I'd like to mock this
     this.closeDialog(true);
  }, error => {
     this.otherFunction(error);
  });
}


// File : myService.ts
saveOject(myObject: MyObject): Promise<any> {
  return this.myApi.save(myOject).toPromise().then(res => res);
}


// File : myApi.ts
save(myObject: MyObject) {
  return this.http.post('url, myObject);
}
```

I'm trying to test this function and I would like to mock (or stub ? I don't know the difference) the saveObject function for when the promise is resolved, and the case it's not.

My actuel test file looks like this:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let myService: MyService;

  beforeEach(async (() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule(
   ).compileComponents();

   myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(myService, 'saveOject').and.returnValue(new Promise(resolve => resolve()));
  });

  it('should call closeDialog method when save form is successful', () => {
     const spyCloseDialog = jest.spyOn(component, 'closeDialog');

     component.save();
     fixture.detectChanges(); // It's a test, I don't know if it's useful
     expect(spyCloseDialog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // It's 0 because I don't know how to be in the then part of my function
  });

}
```

Can somebody help me ? 
Sincerely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to choose from:
1) use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync), for example:

```
it('should call closeDialog method when save form is successful', fakeAsync(() => {
     const spyCloseDialog = jest.spyOn(component, 'closeDialog');

     component.save();
     tick(50);
     expect(spyCloseDialog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

2) put your `expect` inside `then`, for example

```
component.save().then(() => expect(spyCloseDialog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
```

In your test you should import `HttpClientTestingModule`, so that test runs succesfully and no error is thrown when angular tries to fire up a http call.